# Как обновить Recycler view с данными из другого потока?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-asynctask

Я делаю запрос на сайт через `AsyncTask<Strin, Strin, String>` и получаю от туда JSON строку, из которой я беру всё, что мне нужно. Одним словом, всё как обычно, стандартная процедура.
У меня есть `Recycler View`, который мне надо заполнить данными, которые я получил из другого потока. Когда я пытаюсь это сделать, то ничего не происходит. Я позже прочитал, что элементы UI не потока-ориентированные. Как мне заполнить `Recycler View` данными, которые я получаю из другого потока?

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: Очень просто: в `onPostExecute()` передаёте новые данные адаптеру и вызываете ему один из наиболее подходящих вам методов `notifyXXX()`. Метод `onPostExecute()` вызывается в правильном (UI) потоке.

Comment: А тут уже написали onPostExecute() передать туда массив или список и этот метод вызывается в ui потоке. А вообще почитайте про AsyncTask вот гайд, потому что это же элементарные вещи при его использовании: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php

Answer (score 1):

Если на Java, то из рабочего потока в основной можно перейти так, попробуй -

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
//код для основного потока
 }
```

});